# facebook FQL get friend attending to event

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying the get all my facebook friends that are attending to a specific event.

```
select uid, rsvp_status from event_member where uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) AND eid=100609746772815 and  rsvp_status="attending";
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: shouldn´t it be "attending" for the rsvp_status?

Comment: yes, my bad...I edited the question, but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine if you use the permission "friends_events" at the user login. Without that you just get an empty result.